# Responder chain change is breaking my Undo Functionality

Tags: objective-c, appkit

I have a default NSUndoManager set for the current window in my NSWindowDelegate, and that has been functioning great. But now I have modified an NSOutlineView so that its next responder is it's view controller like so:

```
[self.sceneOutlineView setNextResponder:self];
```

So now when the outline view has focus, something seems to be broken with my responder chain, and an NSUndoManager is not set for my Edit menu to use.

I'm a noob to the responder chain. What else do I need to do to figure out how to get my undoManager to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this instead, to fully patch the responder chain:

```
[self setNextResponder:[self.sceneOutlineView nextResponder]];
[self.sceneOutlineView setNextResponder:self];
```

Comment: That worked great! I probably should have tried that. :P I guess I thought that if that was what I was supposed to do, there would have been a one liner for it, a la: [self.sceneOutlineView insertInResponderChain:self];